# IntelliJ "error=86, Bad CPU type in executable" after install fix with Azul?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cpu, azul-zulu

I've seen a few other threads with the similar issue and it seems that downloading a package from Azul is a common fix but I haven't seen any clear instructions on what exactly to do...

Anyone have some tips on fixing this error with Azul?

Comment: Where do you see this error? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: It appears when I try to run a program in the build output. stack doesn't let me post screenshots, but here is the complete error message:

"Cannot run program "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" (in directory "/Users/timothy/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/compile-server"): error=86, Bad CPU type in executable"

Comment: Is it M1 mac? There is a possibility that you are using x86 Java on arm architecture

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.journaldev.com/51374/bad-cpu-type-in-executable-fixed:

- Download the .dmg JDK and install it.
- In IntelliJ, go to Project settings-> Project and change the SDK to AZUL JDK